# Current latest checked out revision?

Tags: svn

How do I see what is the latest version of the SVN repo that is checked out to the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the svnversion command.

http://www.zorched.net/2006/07/20/getting-the-revision-number-of-your-subversion-working-copy/